# Ruby Version Confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, version, conflict

Need a bit of help with installing Ruby and RoR

I installed everything initially last weekend (15/09/2012) including
Ruby, RoR and RubyMine.  I've just opened a Command Prompt on my win 7
64bit box and ran:

```
$ rails --version
```

which to my surprise returned 2.3.14 as I was expecting to see 3.2.8

I then ran:

```
$ gem install rails
```

Which output:

```
Successfully installed rails-3.2.8
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.2.8...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.2.8...
```

Then running `rails --version` again still outputs 2.3.14

I'm a bit confused why a new install (following the instructions here
http://rubyonrails.org/download) seems to have installed a very old
version.

How do I get the latest version installed?

Thanks,

Comment: have you closed and opened cmd?

Comment: You appear on windows. Did you use the RailsInstaller?

Comment: Hi Jesse, I used the "gem install rails" command.  I've just looked at my PATH variable and it only contains "C:\Ruby193\bin" should the PATH variable also contain rails bits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have both versions installed. Run "gem uninstall rails" and it will list the versions and ask which one you want to remove. Then chose the old one to remove.

Comment: Good but better is `gem cleanup rails`.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten a bit further now.  I ran:

```
F:\>gem cleanup rails
Cleaning up installed gems... Attempting to uninstall rails-2.3.14

You have requested to uninstall the gem:
    rails-2.3.14
restful_authentication-1.1.6 depends on [rails (~> 2.3.4)]
If you remove this gems, one or more dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [Yn]  y
Executables and scripts will remain installed.
Successfully uninstalled rails-2.3.14
Clean Up Complete

F:\>gem uninstall restful_authentication
Successfully uninstalled restful_authentication-1.1.6

F:\>gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-3.2.8
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.2.8...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.2.8...

F:\>rails -v
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:317:in `bin_path': can't find ge
m rails ([">= 0"]) with executable rails (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

So now it's telling me that it's installed rails successfully but now errors when I query it's version.